# How to check whether the msi with particular version installed using serverspec?

Tags: rspec, windows-installer, serverspec

We are trying to validate the application installation using ServerSpec in windows. I have written the following lines in ruby file (with Test.rb)

```
require 'spec_helper'

set :backend, :cmd

set :os, :family => 'windows'

describe package('ApplicationCorePackage') do
  it { should be_installed }
end
```

I ran the script like this.

```
rspec 'C:\Ruby Scripts\Test.rb' --format html --out 'C:\Ruby Scripts\Test.html'
```

It is checking that correctly. But i want to check for particular version of the msi(windows installer package). How to do that in serverspec?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean with MSI?

Comment: @SimoneCarletti It is windows installer package.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti I have tried some and modified my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check documentation at: http://serverspec.org/resource_types.html#package

The matcher `be_installed` accepts the chain `with_version`. Therefore, with RSpec 3 syntax we have:

```
describe package('ApplicationCorePackage') do
  it { expect(subject).to be_installed.with_version('version') }
end
```

If your question is whether you need a `by` chain for the MSI provider, then the answer is that you do not.

Comment: what is subject inside expect? Msi has no subject.. Is it product name?

Comment: Subject in this block of code would resolve to `'ApplicationCorePackage'`, i.e. the RSpec method argument.